# How to transfer directories, files and data from the Master Server to the Slave Server

Tags: domain-name-system, network-share

I have a very simple question. And fortunately, I have no coding for this question.

I have configured my Master and Slave servers with BIND and RedHat Linux successfully, and the URL is pointing to my website IP as it is supposed to do.

The database is on a third server, so there is no problem with the database on the two servers. However, I'm concerned with the uploads.

My question is: In this type of configuration, do the changes in the directory, /var/www/html (website files) automatically transfer to the Slave server? And if the answer is no, how can I do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Nope you have to do it yourself, just setup a passwordless key based authentication between the 2 servers and use `rsync` and `cron` to do the job automatically.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found a url that should tell me everything I need to know: https://www.linuxshelltips.com/rsync-files-between-two-linux-servers-automatically/